# Load all user controls of a form on start

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls

My `Winform` application has a main form with a tab control. In each tab there is a `User Control`. And each user control has Controls (such as `DataGridViews`, etc) that are loaded on the Load event of the user control.

The problem I have is that I would like to initialize all these User Controls before my main form is displayed to the user. Currently, the main form is displayed and when the user clicks on one of the tabs, that's when the User Controls start running its Load event and that leaves my main Form blank until the controls are loaded.

So I would like to hide all these loading using a Splash screen that is displayed until all controls are loaded. I have used Splash screen before and I know how to hide and show my main form. The main point is to load all user controls on my main form's Load event.

Comment: You are focusing on solving the wrong problem.  "Loading controls" doesn't do beans, it is retrieving the data that you put in the grid that is expensive.  An obvious fix is to do so in a worker thread so it can't delay the UI rendering.  The next obvious fix is to do it in the constructor instead of the Load event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to loop through each page of the tab control. Winforms only loads a tab page when it is first visited

```
for(int i=1; i < tabControlName.TabPages.Length; i++)
    tabControlName.SelectedIndex = i;
tabControlName.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Changing the selected index will make the tab pages load.

Comment: I think it should be `Count` instead of `Length`.